# Can anyone show me an example of MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef

Tags: c#, .net, methodimplattribute, external-methods

It looks cool on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Specifies that the method is declared, but its implementation is
>   provided elsewhere.

So I tried it in a console application:

```
public class Program
{
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef)]
    public static extern void Invoke();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Invoke();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Then what should I do now? Where can I provide the implementation of `Program.Invoke`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *understanding* is that `ForwardRef` acts in the same way as `extern`, and is intended for guiding the runtime when the language you are using lacks direct support (via `extern` in C#). As such, the usage should be very similar to [the `extern` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), most notably using `[DllImport(...)]`.

Answer (score 16):

The usage of ForwardRef goes pretty much like this:

**consumer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class Foo
{
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef)]
    static extern void Frob();

    static void Main()
    {
        Frob();
    }
}
```

**provider.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class Foo
{
    // Need to declare extern constructor because C# would inject one and break things.
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef)]
    public extern Foo();

    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef)]
    static extern void Main();

    static void Frob()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Now the magic sauce. Open a Visual Studio command prompt and type:

```
csc /target:module provider.cs
csc /target:module consumer.cs
link provider.netmodule consumer.netmodule /entry:Foo.Main /subsystem:console /ltcg
```

This uses one of the lesser known functionality of the linker where we're linking managed modules together. The linker is able to gel together same-shaped types (they need to have the exact same methods, etc.). ForwardRef is the thing that actually lets you provide implementation elsewhere.

This example is kind of pointless, but you can imagine things getting more interesting if a single method is implemented in a different language (e.g. IL).

Comment: Can it be used for interaction with generated code?

Comment: One issue I've come across with the `/ltcg` option with managed code is that it doesn't seem to handle the **IL** `jmp` instruction. With **link.exe** 14.16.27024.1, I consistently crash out with "fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler," followed by "LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed." Since `jmp` is the only CIL opcode that requires tracking fixups between methods, perhaps that's the linker's excuse? I've tried everything. Help?

Comment: p.s. The error also mentions that the error in the **link.exe** source code is at "compiler file 'd:\agent\_work\3\s\src\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\wvm\mdmiscw.c', line 895", if this gives anyone a clue to help me fix this.

Comment: BTW the reason I gave this a bounty is very simple: *this post has vastly transformed my development universe since 2018...* My core Visual Studio projects now mix C# with CIL freely and deeply *within the same assembly/project*, with complete VS debugging, including seamless single-stepping between the two! And no "netmodule" nonsense either. Only things missing are of course "Go-to definition clicking" into the IL and Roslyn analysis of it. You are right about "lesser-known functionality," If not for your answer I might never have found out about `/ltcg`